# Cannot make my bluetooth speakers function with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, speakers

I am having problems making my bluetooth speakers function with ubuntu 20.04. There is no problem pairing / connecting the speakers themselves. After connecting, the speakers show as being the output device in the sound settings, but the sound continues to come out of my laptop's built-in speakers. I had a similar problem with ubuntu 18.04 but could get around it by:

1. pairing the speakers
2. opening the sound settings
3. selecting "speakers-built in audio" (*even though the sound was already coming out of them)
4. closing the sound settings
5. reopening the sound settings
6. choosing " Headset -Lozenge BT" (* the speakers device name)

following the above, the speakers would generally come on. It was a pain in the arse though.
Sometimes I would have to reboot the laptop entirely to get them to work.

I have since upgraded to 20.04 and still have the same problem, only now the above get-around does not work and I cannot get the sound to come out of the bluetooth speakers at all.
Any help with this would be appreciated. I am not a programmer so please be as simple and explicit as possible if you respond.

Thx

Comment: Pardon me @guiverc.... I am using the 20.04 release

Comment: Thank you for the advice @guiverc... I have edited the post.